# MediaRecorder instance not released

Tags: android

I am making an android application to record sound. I have been using class MediaRecorder for that.

The recording is done successfully when the recording is done for the first time on any device. But it doesn't work next time.

If I try the code on another machine, recording is done successfully. Is it so because MediaRecorder instance is not getting released by the app even if I am calling method `release()`.

This is my code-

```
 public class NewClass extends Activity {
private static String sFileName = null;
private static String sFileNameMSD = null;
private static String sPlayFile = null;
public MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private String mPn_id;
private String mDescription;
private String mTask_flag;
private String mPatient_name;
private String mPatient_id;
private String mIs_upload = "N";
private Context mContext;
Button btnStart;
Button btnStop;
private int mReuqestcode;
NewClass myActivity;
SeekBar seekBar;
int totalTime;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final String FILE_EXTENTION_AMR = ".amr";
private final String FILE_EXTENTION_MSD = ".msd";
protected boolean recodeFlag = false;;
private static final String TAG = GridAllActivity.class.getName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.transcriptionrecord_activity);
    mContext = this;
    myActivity = this;
    Main.setTitle(myActivity, mContext);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(
            mContext));
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Title1);
    txtTitle.setText("Transcription");
    TextView txtOption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOptionName);
    TextView txtPatientName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPatientName);
    setProperty();
    txtOption.setText("" + mDescription);
    txtPatientName.setText("" + mPatient_name);
}
private void onRecord(boolean start) throws SettingNotFoundException {
    if (start) {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
        }
}

private void startRecording() throws SettingNotFoundException {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(sFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {

        mRecorder.prepare();

        mRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        recodeFlag=true;
        Log.e("1", "prepare() failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void stopRecording() throws SettingNotFoundException {

    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    Log.d("1", "mRecorder released");
    mRecorder = null;
    System.gc();
}

public void setRecordPath() throws IOException {

    sFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    sFileName += Global.creteFolderPath("IMSEMR" + mTask_flag + "_"
            + mPn_id + FILE_EXTENTION_AMR);
    sFileNameMSD = "IMSEMR" + mTask_flag + "_" + mPn_id
            + FILE_EXTENTION_MSD;
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Global.alertbox("", "SD Card is not mounted.", mContext);
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                + ".");
    }

    File directory = new File(sFileName).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

}

public void setRecodingLayout() {

    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    try {
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean mStartRecording = true;
                try {
                    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                    onRecord(mStartRecording);

                } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });         
                    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                boolean mStartRecording = false;
                try {
                    onRecord(mStartRecording);
                } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
                        }
        });

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}

public void setProperty() {
    Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();
    mReuqestcode = (Integer) bundel.get("REQUEST_CODE");
    // property for Record
    if (mReuqestcode == 1) {
        mPn_id = (String) bundel.get("PN_ID");
        mDescription = (String) bundel.get("DESCRIPTION");
        mTask_flag = (String) bundel.get("TASK_FLAG");
        mPatient_id = (String) bundel.get("PATIENT_ID");
        mPatient_name = (String) bundel.get("PATIENT_NAME");
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStop.setEnabled(false);
        setRecodingLayout();
        try {
            setRecordPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of media recorder each time you want to record (making sure to release the previous one).

Update --
Sorry, you only need to create a new instance if you call [release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#release%28%29) on the object. Otherwise you can just call [reset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#reset%28%29), 
read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Example:
Lets say you have an activity with 2 buttons, a record button and a play button

```
public class MyRecordDemo extends Activity {
   private static final String PATH_NAME = "/sdcard/myfile.3gp"; //probably shouldn't hardcode this
   private Button mRecordButton, mStopButton;
   private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
   private boolean mIsRecording = false;
   public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
      super.onCreate(state);
      setContentView(R.layout.recorder_demo);
      mRecordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_btn);
      mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);
      mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (mIsRecording && mRecorder != null) {
               mRecorder.stop(); 
               mRecorder.release();
             }
          }
      });
      mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if (mIsRecording && mRecorder != null) {
              mRecorder.stop(); 
              mRecorder.release();
           }
           mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
           mRecorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
           mRecorder.prepare();
           mRecorder.start()
        }

      });
   }

}
```

Comment: This is my code
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(sFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();

I'm creating new instance of MEDIARECORDER each time for recording.
Don't know what is the problem. I'm getting prepare() failed error every time after first recording on any device.

Comment: edit your question and put your code there.. Not just the code above but the whole activity if possible.